# What is needed to call SQL Server Stored Procedure from Salesforce?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, salesforce, ssis-2017

I've been asked to execute/call Stored Procedure from Salesforce.

I'm using SQL Server 2017 Enterprise.

**What do I need to execute/call a SQL Server stored procedures from Salesforce?**

Comment: I think the Salesforce hook is the important thing.  Absolutely stored procedures are made to be called by outside programs.  It sounds like this is a Salesforce api question.

Comment: I did an edit to make the question more direct -  less "yes/no".  Could you specify the versions of SQL Server and of Salesforce?

Comment: Unfortunately the edits have added more confusion to an unclear question. Do you want to execute a stored procedure from Salesforce or run a SSIS package? No matter which, a simple search indicates you can't do this [directly](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/86343/connect-to-external-database-from-salesforce).

Comment: @SMor it sounds like OP wants to call a SQL stored proc, from Salesforce, that will execute an SSIS package.

Comment: You will need an api to call your sql stored procedure. You can spin one up relatively easy with heroku and using a library to connect to your SQL Server instance.

Comment: Here's a pretty informative post on how to execute SSIS packages from a SQL stored proc: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2992/how-to-execute-an-integration-services-ssis-package-from-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/

Comment: @digital.aaron great resource, thanks Aaron